# is there an event like onRouteChange in SolidJs?

Tags: javascript, url, routes, solid-js

I need to run some logic every time the url changes.

My application uses solid-app-router
https://github.com/solidjs/solid-router

How can I subscribe to router changes in SolidJS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`solid-app-router` has a `useLocation` primitive (hook).
useLocation gives access to `location` which is a store-like object meaning its properties are reactive.

So, in one word, to have the chance to run code on every url change, all we have to do is to wrap `location.pathname` with a `createEffect()` hook

```
import { useLocation } from "solid-app-router";


export function MyComponent() {

    const location = useLocation();

    createEffect(() => {
       
        console.log(location.pathname);
    })

 // ...
```